# Why zoom level of google map is not working in android emulator?

Tags: android, google-maps

I use emulator nexus 4 on windows 7.

I created this method to display a city on google maps:

```
    public void openMap() {
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            Uri uri = builder.scheme("geo").path("0,0").
appendQueryParameter("q","Lviv, Lviv Oblast, Ukraine").appendQueryParameter("z","5").build();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

But when i change query parameter `z` to 20 or 15, it doesn't work. Google map always opens at the same zoom level.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

[Zoom levels](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Zoomlevels)

> not all zoom levels appear at all locations on the earth. Zoom levels vary depending on location, as data in some parts of the globe is more granular than in other locations.
>   If you send a request for a zoom level at which no map tiles are available, the Google Static Maps API will return a map showing the maximum zoom level available at that location.